# google chart column name with special characters

Tags: google-visualization, special-characters, axis-labels

I have the following data being passed to a google chart:

```
[['2014/12', 'Flag Officer', 'Account Services', 'Cashier&rsquo;s check', 1],['2014/12', 'Flag Officer', 'Credit Cards', 'Credit monitoring', 1]]
```

The above should result in the chart displaying  2 bars ( I'm using column 3 & 4 for the charts ). The chart displays the bars as expected, except for the fact that the column labels are displayed as follows:

```
Cashier&rsquo;s check and Credit monitoring
```

instead of

> Cashier’s check and Credit monitoring

I have searched for a solution. All I can find, is a solution to manage the chart title but nothing on managing the chart column labels. Any help or pointers in this regard will be greatly appreciated.